# The feature data generated by the dataset lacks the required input key 'dense_Dense1_input'

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm trying to load data from a CSV any fitting a model to it. Here's the (simplified) code:

```
import { data, layers, sequential } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

const dataset = data.csv('file://C:\\Users\\rgott\\Projects\\tensorflow-js-node\\data.csv', {
    columnConfigs: {
        PurchasePrice: {
            isLabel: true,
            dtype: 'float32',
        },
        LivingArea: {
            dtype: 'float32',
            required: true,
        },
        GardenArea: {
            dtype: 'float32',
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    configuredColumnsOnly: true,
    hasHeader: true,
    delimiter: ',',
});

const model = sequential({
    layers: [
        layers.dense({inputShape: [2], units: 5, activation: 'relu'}),
        layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'softmax'}),
    ],
});
model.compile({optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'meanSquaredError'})
await model.fitDataset(dataset, {epochs: 10});
```

The data looks like this:

```
PurchasePrice,LivingArea,GardenArea,HasBalcony,HasElevator,HasTerrace,IncludedParkingSpots,Rooms,YearOfConstruction,FirstTimeUse
"178,695","35.5",,Yes,Yes,Yes,0,2,,Yes
"315,000",112,,No,No,No,0,,,No
"589,000","124.33","54.69",No,No,Yes,0,5,,Yes
"387,030","79.01",,Yes,Yes,Yes,0,3,,Yes
...
```

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The feature data generated by the dataset lacks the required input key 'dense_Dense1_input'.

I've searched Google and SO for hours, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Why is it looking for some kind of input name? Shouldn't it just take all the values from the Xs as the input?

Some more context just in case:

- `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`: `2.1.0`
- `ts-node`: `8.10.2`
- `typescript`: `3.9.7`
- Windows 10
- Node 10.16